# ¿Cómo puedo realizar pruebas en flutter desde mi celular haciendo peticiones http a mi api rest en flask?

Tags: python, android, flutter, dart, flask

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en *flutter*, la cual consume una api rest la cual está desarrollada con *flask*. La aplicación gestiona hasta el momento el login, la recuperación de la contraseña, un token de verificación, ocupando *riverpod* para el manejo de los estados y *go_router* para las rutas.

El problema surge cuando trato de probar mi aplicación en mi celular físico, ya que me da este error:

> I/flutter (11209): ClientException with SocketException: No route to
> host (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113), address =
> 192.168.4.22, port = 47818, uri=http://192.168.4.22:5000/api/auth/login

Según lo que he leído es porque no encuentra el servidor `192.168.4.22:5000`, pero para correrlo en el emulador según lo que leí es que debo ocupar la url `http://10.0.2.2:5000/api` y me funciona perfecto, logro hacer el login, la recuperación de la contraseña, el registro y se guarda en la base de datos que a todo esto es postgresql, pero para correrlo desde el celular físico que es donde tengo este problema, según lo que investigué debo ocupar la direccion ip de mi computadora la cual es la que se describe más arriba (`http://192.168.4.22:5000/api`) pero es ahí donde me da este error ya descrito.

Para realizar las peticiones estoy utilizando *http*.

Dejo una imagen del error con la impresión de la ruta del endpoint, el body, content-type:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También debo agregar que tengo mi api rest corriendo el puerto 5000

- Running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000`

Este es mi archivo de *app.py* en *flask*

```
from flask import Flask
from config import config

from routes import Auth_route
from routes import User_route

app=Flask(__name__)

def page_not_found(error):
    return "<h1>Not found page...!!</h1>",404

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.config.from_object(['development'])


    # Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(Auth_route.main, url_prefix='/api/auth')
    app.register_blueprint(User_route.main, url_prefix='/api')

    # Error Handlers
    app.register_error_handler( 404, page_not_found )
    app.run(debug=True)
    app.run()
```

Tal vez deba realizar alguna configuración en *flask*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con wifi de su celular físico apagado.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Esto suena a que podría ser un problema de tu red/modem.

Primero es recomendable separar el WiFi 2.4GHz y 5GHz para que tanto el teléfono como la computadora donde se encuentre el servidor se encuentren en exactamente la misma red.

También verifica el Aislamiento del Cliente se encuentre deshabilitado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y jamás está demás que revises de nuevo Dirección IPV4 desde el CMD con comando ipconfig /all

Saludos y suerte.